# STM32 - EEProm emulation example - how to determine / automatically assign start address without conflict

Tags: stm32, eeprom

I am not sure, if I missed some information the documents I read, but I struggle with the following issue.

I want to implement an emulated EEPROM in my software for an STM32F103 (physically a STM32F103C8).
So I went trough the [application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2594-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), and the software sample code (STM32Cube\Repository\STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.8.4).

In the file *eeprom.h* the following is defined:

```
/* Define the size of the sectors to be used */
#define PAGE_SIZE               (uint32_t)FLASH_PAGE_SIZE  /* Page size */

/* EEPROM start address in Flash */
#define EEPROM_START_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t)ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_32) /* EEPROM emulation start address */

/* Pages 0 and 1 base and end addresses */
#define PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x0000))
#define PAGE0_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)))
#define PAGE0_ID               ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_32

#define PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x10000))
#define PAGE1_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x10000 + PAGE_SIZE - 1))
#define PAGE1_ID               ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_96
```

Maybe I am overthinking this or miss something, but EEPROM_START_ADDRESS is defined hard coded here as PAGE_32.

So my questions:

- I guess, this start value is application defined and should be selected by me according my program size?
- How would I determine what page is not being used otherwise / by the program?
- In best case, is there a way to automatically assign the first empty page not used by the program during compile?

Additionally (but not so important) question - I cant find, where "FLASH_PAGE_SIZE" is defined? Is it a compiler variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess, this start value is application defined and should be selected by me according my program size?

Yes, the "EEPROM" start address should be determined by you, based on your application needs.

However, you would typically not choose the next free page. A common strategy is to select the however many pages you need from the end of the FLASH region, this way, your program can grow without overwriting the saved data.

Comment: Got it, but then the example of ST is simply confusing. Why on earth would they then use Page32 for page0 and page 96 for page 1....

Comment: @KarlKarlsom I guess they're just trying to illustrate the fact that you can map the pages in any way you like.